# How to summon a custom item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making i parkour map with lucky blocks (no mod) and i made everything except the command for the command block. i want to summon a diamond sword with the enchantment id of 16. iv tried this: `/summon minecraft:item 320 4 468 {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]}}}`. It doesn't work.

I tried the `/give` version: `give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"Lucky Sword"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}]}`. Still, only gives normal diamond sword!

I'm on 1.13 version on PC.

Please help!

Comment: All this does is summon a normal diamond sword.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, you can try below this command:

```
/summon minecraft:item ~ ~ ~2 {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:10}]}}}
```